# Back navigation in mixed drawer navigator, stack navigator, bottom tab navigator and top tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I want to implement a functionality where if we click on back button we go to the previous page rather than the hardcoded back buttons which we have given. I have stack screen and drawer screen mixed so I am not able to implement the desired functionality. This is the first time i am asking for an answer kindly let me know if there is any more information needed. I am attaching one screen which shows the hardcoded back button

Below is the code for MainDrawerNavigation

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MainDrawerNavigation({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home Dashboard"
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: theme.COLORS.WHITE,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
        },
        drawerActiveTintColor: theme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
        drawerContentContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fff" },
        sceneContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home Dashboard"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          sceneContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screen1" component={SampleScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screen2" component={SampleScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screen3" component={SampleScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screen4" component={SampleScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="LoginScreen"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Forgot Password"
        component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Users" component={Users} />

      <Drawer.Screen name="Accounts" component={Accounts} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Branches" component={Branches} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Fleets" component={Fleets} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Vehicles" component={Vehicles} />

      <Drawer.Screen name="Manage User" component={ManageUser} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Manage Branch" component={ManageBranch} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Change Password" component={ChangePasswordScreen} />

      <Drawer.Screen name="Manage Account" component={ManageAccount} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Manage Fleet" component={ManageFleet} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Manage Vehicle" component={ManageVehicle} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Vehicle"
        component={EditVehicle}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="close"
              size={24}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Manage Vehicle")}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Vehicle"
        component={AddVehicle}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-back"
              size={24}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Vehicles")}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Meter Reading"
        component={AddMeterReadingScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          // headerLeft: () => (
          //   <Ionicons
          //     name='arrow-back'
          //     size={24}
          //     color='white'
          //     style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
          //     onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Manage Vehicle")}
          //   />
          // ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Meter Reading"
        component={ManageMeterReadingScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-back"
              size={24}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Vehicles")}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Fuel Event"
        component={AddFuelEvent}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Fuel Events"
        component={ManageFuelEvents}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Meter Reading"
        component={EditMeterReadingsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-back"
              size={24}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Vehicles")}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Fuel Event"
        component={EditFuelEvent}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Warranty"
        component={AddWarranty}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Warranty"
        component={EditWarranty}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Warranty"
        component={ManageWarranty}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Repair Order"
        component={AddRepairOrderScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Repair Order"
        component={ManageRepairOrdersScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Images and Line Items"
        component={ImagesAndLineItemsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Repair Order"
        component={EditRepairOrderScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Line Items"
        component={EditLineItemsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add PM"
        component={AddPreventiveMaintenance}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage PM"
        component={ManagePreventiveMaintenance}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit PM"
        component={EditPM}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Invoice Summary"
        component={InvoiceSummaryScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Invoice Summary Listing"
        component={InvoiceSummaryListingScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Fuel Tax Report"
        component={FuelTaxReportScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Repair Orders Dashboard"
        component={RepairOrdersDashBoard}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Repair Orders"
        component={AddRepairOrderForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Line Items"
        component={AddLineItemsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Fuel Tax Report Listing"
        component={FuelTaxReportListingScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cost Per Mile Summary"
        component={CostPerMileSummaryScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cost Per Mile Summary Run Report"
        component={CostPerMileSummaryRunReport}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cost Per Mile Detailed"
        component={CostPerMileDetailedScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cost Per Mile Detailed Run Report"
        component={CostPerMileDetailedRunReport}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Preventive Maintenance"
        component={PreventiveMaintenanceForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Preventive Maintenance"
        component={ManagePreventiveMaintenanceForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Preventive Maintenance"
        component={AddPreventiveMaintenanceForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Preventive Maintenance"
        component={EditPreventiveMaintenanceForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Manage Repair Orders"
        component={ManageRepairOrdersForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Repair Orders"
        component={EditRepairOrderForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Images and Line Item"
        component={ImagesAndLineItemsForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Add Line Item"
        component={AddLineItemsForFleetManagement}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#006AB4", // Customize the background color
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff", // Customize the text color
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Below is the code for hardcoded back button screen:

```
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

import ContextMenu from "../components/icons/ContextMenu";
import ManageAccountCard from "../components/ManageAccountCard";
import { commonStyles } from "../components/StyleComponent";
import ManageFleetCard from "../components/ManageFleetCard";

import theme from "../constants/Theam";
import { getAccount } from "../utility/account-services";
import ManageFleetFilter from "../components/ManageFleetFilter";
import { IconButton } from "react-native-paper";
import { getFleet, manageFleetSearchVehicles } from "../utility/fleet-services";
import { manageFleetgetVehicle } from "../utility/vehicle-services";

function ManageFleet() {
  const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState({});
  const [isFilterOpen, setIsFilterOpen] = useState(false);
  const [vehicleUnitNumber, setVehicleUnitNumber] = useState(null);
  const [isResponseEmpty, setIsResponseEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const route = useRoute();
  const { fleetsId } = route.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <IconButton
          icon="magnify"
          iconColor="white"
          onPress={() => setIsFilterOpen(true)}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, []);

  const [fleets, setFleet] = useState([]);
  const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState([]);
  const [branchName, setBranchName] = useState("");
  const [branchId, setBranchId] = useState("");
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFleets = async () => {
      const payload = await getFleet(fleetsId);
      console.log("get fleet data", payload);
      // if (payload.status !== 200) {
      //   navigation.navigate("Users");
      // }
      if (payload.status === 200 && Object.keys(payload.data).length === 0) {
        setIsUserEmpty(true);
      } else {
        setFleet(payload);
        setBranchName(payload["branch"].name);
        setBranchId(payload.branch_id);
        setUserId(payload["branch"].client_id);
        // setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchFleets();
  }, [fleetsId, navigation]);

  let requiredData;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVehicles = async () => {
      const payload = await manageFleetgetVehicle(fleetsId);
      setAccountName(payload[0]?.client_name);

      requiredData = payload.map((obj) => {
        const { name, created_at, id, vehicle_number } = obj;
        return { name, created_at, id, vehicle_number };
      });
      // if (payload.status !== 200) {
      //   navigation.navigate("Users");
      // }
      if (payload.status === 200 && Object.keys(payload.data).length === 0) {
        setIsUserEmpty(true);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        setVehicles(requiredData);

        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchVehicles();
  }, [fleetsId, navigation]);

  const searchVehicles = async (searchedVehicleUnitNumber) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (searchedVehicleUnitNumber === null) {
      setIsResponseEmpty(false);
      const fetchVehicles = async () => {
        const payload = await manageFleetgetVehicle(fleetsId);
        const requiredData = payload.map((obj) => {
          const { name, created_at, id, vehicle_number } = obj;
          return { name, created_at, id, vehicle_number };
        });
        setVehicles(requiredData);

        // if (payload.status !== 200) {
        //   navigation.navigate("Users");
        // }
      };
      fetchVehicles();
    } else {
      const searchedVehicles = await manageFleetSearchVehicles(
        vehicleUnitNumber,
        fleetsId
      );

      if (searchedVehicles.length === 0 || searchedVehicles === undefined) {
        // setSearchResultEmpty(true);
        setIsResponseEmpty(true);
      } else {
        // setSearchResultEmpty(false);
        // setSearchResult(searchedUser[0]);
        setIsResponseEmpty(false);
        let requiredData = searchedVehicles.map((obj) => {
          const { vehicle_number, created_at } = obj;
          return { vehicle_number, created_at };
        });
        setVehicles(requiredData);
      }
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <>
        <View style={styles.accountCard}>
          <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.nameBold}>{fleets.name}</Text>
            <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.key}>Name:</Text>
              <Text>{fleets.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.key}>Account</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate("Manage Account", { userId })
                }
              >
                <Text style={styles.link}>{accountName}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.key}>Branch:</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate("Manage Branch", { branchId })
                }
              >
                <Text style={styles.link}>{branchName}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.key}>Fleet Number:</Text>
              <Text>{fleets.fleet_number}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </>
      {isResponseEmpty && (
        <View style={commonStyles.emptyResponse}>
          <Text>No Data Found</Text>
          <ManageFleetFilter
            isBottomSheetOpen={isFilterOpen}
            setIsBottomSheetOpen={setIsFilterOpen}
            vehicleUnitNumber={vehicleUnitNumber}
            setVehicleUnitNumber={setVehicleUnitNumber}
            searchVehicles={searchVehicles}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      {!isResponseEmpty && !isLoading && (
        <>
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}>
            <Text style={styles.nameBold}>Vehicles</Text>
          </View>
          <FlatList
            data={vehicles}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ManageFleetCard
                vehicleNumber={item.vehicle_number}
                createdAt={item.created_at}
                vehicleId={item.id}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            style={styles.flatList}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={commonStyles.backButton}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Fleets")}
          >
            <View style={commonStyles.backButtonTextContainer}>
              <Text style={commonStyles.backButtonText}>Back</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <ManageFleetFilter
            isBottomSheetOpen={isFilterOpen}
            setIsBottomSheetOpen={setIsFilterOpen}
            vehicleUnitNumber={vehicleUnitNumber}
            setVehicleUnitNumber={setVehicleUnitNumber}
            searchVehicles={searchVehicles}
          />
        </>
      )}
      {isLoading && (
        <View style={commonStyles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default ManageFleet;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  accountCard: {
    margin: 16,
    padding: 16,
    shadowColor: theme.THEME_COLORS.black,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: Platform.OS === "android" ? 5 : null,
    borderRadius: Platform.OS === "android" ? 1 : null,
    backgroundColor: theme.THEME_COLORS.white,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  nameBold: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  infoContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  key: {
    marginRight: 8,
    color: theme.THEME_COLORS.grayText,
  },
  flatList: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  link: {
    color: theme.THEME_COLORS.primary,
  },
});
```